# iOS Google maps SDK load custom region, language map

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

in JS, if we want the google map to load with a different region+language, we can change it by simply altering the connecion string:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={APIKEY}&region=VN&language=vi&libraries=places,geometry
```

But in iOS Google Maps SDK, it looks like this isn't doable. Instead, the phone's region and language must be set to VN/VI to get the desired map.

This is bad, because the Vietnamese govt has criminalised map views other than what we get with VN+VI in google maps. If the region is set to Vietnam but phone language is still English, then the map loaded is showing areas/names that end up violating some strict rules there (mainly the name of the sea and some islands which are disputed territories).

So is there a way in iOS to force google maps to load in a set region and language like VN/VI even if the phone's current region/language is different?

Comment: SAME ISSUE HAVE YOU FIND ANY WAY ?

Comment: We couldn't get the language to change just for the map. Made the map pan back to user's location if it goes too far away (like: 0.3 degrees lat or lon) from the user's location. And restricted the min zoom to 8 or so. This way the user will never be able to browse the map to the problem areas, and will never be able to zoom out far enough to see the problem areas.